# Layout not rendering in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I was trying out some projects in Android Studio and I came across this error which I am not able to figure out.
One of the layouts in the app is not rendering in the IDE. But it is visible if I run the app. There are no issues with other layouts in the app. Only the main layout, activity_main.xml has the problem.
It is showing the following errors as well.

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

**I already tried deleting Android Studio and Gradle cache, Clean, and Rebuild. Invalidate Caches / Restart did not work as well.**

Please help me with this as I am stuck in my self-learning of Andriod development.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Delete below line from all **EditText** tags

```
android:autofillHints=""
```

XML Rendering will work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering the question. I'm so grateful. I'm just starting development after a long time and my eyes are not catching up with the code where it should.